# walk / traverse folder in AutoHotkey?

Tags: tree, directory, autohotkey, traversal

I've searched the ahk docs and the ahk forum, but I can't find a folder tree traversal example.  Does anyone have a good example of this for AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I didn't look thoroughly enough in the ahk docs...
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm